# awk + add rules to awk command

Tags: awk

I have the following awk command

```
   awk  '{if ( $2 == "x.name" ) {print "OK"} else {print "NOT OK" } }'
```

but $2 could be x.name or x-name or x:name

how to change the following awk in order to
Support all rules (x.name or x-name or x:name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk  '{if ( $2 ~ /x[-.:]name/ ) {print "OK"} else {print "NOT OK" } }'
```